# createSelector is returning its equalityCheck function instead of the value

Tags: react-redux, reselect

By the sake of understanding better `createSelector`, I'm trying to use it instead of `useSelector`

```
const domainEntitlements = useSelector((state) => state.objects.domainEntitlements[match.params.id]);
const domainEntitlement = createSelector((state) => state.objects.domainEntitlements, (domainEntitlements) => (domainEntitlements));
  console.log(domainEntitlements, domainEntitlement);
```

the `useSelector` logs an object (correct), but the `createSelector` logs an `equalityCheck` function.

[image]

Am I doing something very stupid or why I can get the data with `useSelector` and not with `createSelector`?

Answer (score 0):

CreateSelector returns a function, this function you can pass to useSelector as an argument.

CreateSelector is used to specify logic to where data is located in the state or how data is derived only once and re use them in other selectors. Here is how you can use your selector in the component:

```
const selectObjects = (state) => state.objects;
const selectDomainEntitlements = createSelector(
  [selectObjects], //re use selectObjects
  (objects) => objects.domainEntitlements
);
const createSelectDomainEntitlementById = (id) =>
  createSelector(
    [selectDomainEntitlements], //re use selecting domain entitlements
    (domainEntitlements) => domainEntitlements[id]
  );

//example of using the selector in your component
const Component = () => {
  const domainEntitlement = useSelector(
    createSelectDomainEntitlementById(match.params.id)
  );
};
```

A more detailed explanation on selectors and how to possibly optimize your app by using memoization can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors/blob/master/README.md)